# ThrottlingException - Update JOB_POLL_INTERVAL in airflow DAG AwsGlueJobOperator

Tags: airflow, aws-glue, throttling

I am running an Airflow DAG ad using AwsGlueJobOperator to run AWS Glue job. Below is the sample code for reference.

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import AwsGlueJobOperator

with DAG(dag_id=dag_id, default_args=default_args) as dag:

task1 = AwsGlueJobOperator(
    job_name='SampleJobName',
    dag=dag
    )
```

I am getting below error:
**ERROR - An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the GetJobRun operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded**

My Glue job is running more than 1 hour because it is processing large amount of data and airflow is calling too many GetJobRun in every 6 seconds.

I want to update the hook value (JOB_POLL_INTERVAL) of 6 seconds to 20 seconds just for this DAG:

```
airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.glue
```

Any suggestions how we can we achive this?

Answer (score 0):

update : 25 july 2023

since apache-airflow-providers-amazon version 8.3.0

you can custom the `job_poll_interval`

---

you can't custom this setting with the current implementation